# where is the sandbox methods (like sb.getContainer() , sb.getModel() ) defined in the scaleApp.js framework?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have a rudimentary question about this great js framework http://www.scaleapp.org . I am unable to locate the code for the sandbox(sb) object thats used in the code (i am new to coffeescript) .

source code for the framework - https://github.com/flosse/scaleApp

source code for the demo test - https://github.com/flosse/FAST/blob/master/modules/box/box.js

Any help would be great! Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to edit your question to be more precise?

You can find the sandbox class here:

```
https://github.com/flosse/scaleApp/blob/master/src/Sandbox.coffee
```

Also have a look at the [Quick Start](https://github.com/flosse/scaleApp/blob/master/README.markdown#quick-start) section within the README.